# ngModel doesn't pass data back to parent scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

Related Post, but didn't help:
[Scoping issue when setting ngModel from a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045980/scoping-issue-when-setting-ngmodel-from-a-directive)

EDIT: [Can I use ng-model with isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope) didn't work either.

I got the some problem but in a more complex way I guess. I want to write a pulldown that does not use any input for data saving. I'd rather have the ngModel to take care of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/QeM6g/6/

The jsFiddle example above shows a demo where the above described methods didn't work.

```
// this is what should work but doesn't
ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
scope.$apply(attr.ngModel,value);
```

For some reason the scope of the ngModelController is a sibling of my scope. so it doesn't pass the changes back to the parent. at least all other sibling scopes behave as you'd expect. i.e. ng-change works in combination.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Angularjs doesn't deal very well with direct bindings to primitive types.

If you change this line:

```
$scope.productId = 16;
```

to something like this:

```
$scope.selectedProduct = {
    id: 16
}
```

and change those references on the rest of the code, you should be able to overcome the issue.

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/M2cL7/

Comment: Thanks, I would have never guessed that. Saved me a sleepless nights. I reported this as [issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1913) for all who want to know if that behavior will be fixed.

Comment: @bmleite Its not a problem with angular's data binding. Its about javascript prototyping. Please read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 7):

Don't bind to primitives in a scope, bind to an object in the scope.

From https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

> ... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It
>   doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens
>   is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the
>   parent property of the same name. **This is not something AngularJS is
>   doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works**. New
>   AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch,
>   ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem
>   often shows up when these directives are involved.
>
> **This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models**

so

```
<input ng-model="tweetText">
```

becomes

```
<input ng-model="tweet.text">
```

A great summary is here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOOUUUUUU!!