# Bind ngModel to AngularJS directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to build an Angular directive that renders radio inputs and the associated labels. The HTML for the directive looks like this:

```
<d-radio name="gender" value="male" label="I'm a male"></d-radio>
<d-radio name="gender" value="female" label="I'm a female"></d-radio>
```

I'd like it render the equivalent of this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" ng-model="gender"><label for="male">I'm a male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" ng-model="gender"><label for="female">I'm a female</label>
```

And here's the JS code:

```
app.directive('dRadio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        template: '<input type="radio" id="{{value}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}"><label for="{{value}}">{{label}}</label>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = attrs.name;
            scope.value = attrs.value;
            scope.label = attrs.label;
        }
    };
});
```

The only thing missing from my directive is the ng-model portion. Since each directive creates an isolated scope, I'm not sure how to bind the model to it.

There is a similar Stack Overflow question here:
[Isolating directive scope but preserve binding on ngModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367550/isolating-directive-scope-but-preserve-binding-on-ngmodel)

I tried this solution, but I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/586COA8rCl0hlqcS47G1?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a bi-directional binding you will need to add an `model: '='` to your scope. That will allow you to have a model variable in your scope which will be binded with the one you indicate in the html

```
app.directive('dRadio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { model: '=' },
        template: '<input type="radio" ng-model="{{model}}" id="{{value}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}">    <label for="{{value}}">{{label}}</label>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = attrs.name;
            scope.value = attrs.value;
            scope.label = attrs.label;
        }
    };
});
```

And in your html

```
<d-radio name="gender" value="male" label="I'm a male" model="gender"></d-radio>
```

Comment: Works great! Fantastic answer! I will upvote this once I have 15 reputation points.